# Sqlalchemy: versioned models, secondary and secondaryjoin

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here is the setup:

There are a Missions for car (travel from point A to point B, for example) -
model named **Mission**.

Mission cars(model named **Car**) are versioned by dates (see model bellow)

A car have a GPS device(model named **GPS**), which is used to send signals of
current position.
GPS devices also versioned by dates(see model bellow).

Attachment of GPS device to car(model named **CArGPS**) are also versioned
(see model bellow)
(Yes, it is very complicated and i can't change schema.)

Problem: setup relations that way, so i can get version of mission
car(by **Mission.date_start**) and get version of gps device attached to this car
version (by **Mission.date_start**).

In terns if SQL it would be:

```
SELECT
  mission.id               AS mission_id,
  mission.date_start       AS mission_date_start,
  mission.car_id           AS mission_car_id,
  car_1.id                 AS car_1_id,
  car_1.car_id             AS car_1_car_id,
  car_1.start_date         AS car_1_start_date,
  car_1.end_date           AS car_1_end_date,
  car_1.version_start_date AS car_1_version_start_date,
  car_1.version_end_date   AS car_1_version_end_date,
  car_gps_1.id             AS car_gps_1_id,
  car_gps_1.gps_id         AS car_gps_1_gps_id,
  car_gps_1.car_id         AS car_gps_1_car_id,
  car_gps_1.start_date     AS car_gps_1_start_date,
  car_gps_1.end_date       AS car_gps_1_end_date,
  gps_1.gps_code           AS gps_1_gps_code
FROM mission

  LEFT OUTER JOIN car AS car_1 ON car_1.car_id = mission.car_id AND
                                  car_1.start_date <= mission.date_start AND
                                  car_1.end_date >= mission.date_start AND
                                  car_1.version_start_date <= mission.date_start AND
                                  car_1.version_end_date >= mission.date_start

  LEFT OUTER JOIN car_gps AS car_gps_1 ON car_gps_1.car_id = mission.car_id AND
                                          car_gps_1.start_date <= mission.date_start AND
                                          car_gps_1.end_date >= mission.date_start

  LEFT OUTER JOIN gps as gps_1 ON gps_1.id = car_gps_1.id AND
                                  gps_1.start_date <= mission.date_start AND
                                  gps_1.end_date >= mission.date_start
```

*So i want query, like*

```
query = session.query(Mission).options(
    joinedload(Mission.car), joinedload(Mission.car_device)
)
results = query.all()

# and get gps code of mission car

gps_code = query.Mission.car_device.gps_code
```

Models code and etc.:

```
class GPS(Base):
    '''Version of gps-device'''
    __tablename__ = 'gps'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    gps_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)
    end_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)
    gps_code = Column(VARCHAR(20))


class Car(Base):
    '''Version of car'''
    __tablename__ = 'car'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)
    end_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)
    version_start_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)
    version_end_date = Column(Date(), primary_key=True)


class CarGPS(Base):
    '''Version of attachment of gps-device to car'''
    __tablename__ = 'car_gps'

    id = Column(Integer(), nullable=False)
    gps_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(GPS.gps_id), primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.car_id), primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), primary_key=True)
    end_date = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), primary_key=True)


class Mission(Base):
    '''Car mission'''
    __tablename__ = 'mission'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    date_start = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False))
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))

    # Version of mission car
    car = relationship(Car,
                       primaryjoin=and_(Car.car_id == car_id,
                                        Car.start_date <= date_start,
                                        Car.end_date >= date_start,
                                        Car.version_start_date <= date_start,
                                        Car.version_end_date >= date_start),
                       foreign_keys=car_id,
                       uselist=False, viewonly=True)
    # Version of mission car gpd-device attachment
    car_gps = relationship(CarGPS,
                           primaryjoin=and_(CarGPS.car_id == car_id,
                                            CarGPS.start_date <= date_start,
                                            CarGPS.end_date >= date_start),
                           foreign_keys=CarGPS.car_id,
                           uselist=False, viewonly=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
# This query is good but without GPS device of car
query = session.query(Mission).options(
    joinedload(Mission.car), joinedload(Mission.car_gps)
)

query.all()
```

I'am new to sqlAlchemy and can't understand how to setup such relation for
GPS device. May be it can be achieved using secondary and secondaryjoin
attributes of relationship?

Currently it can be achieved by this query:

```
query = query.outerjoin(CarGPS, and_(
                    CarGPS.car_id == Mission.car_id,
                    CarGPS.start_date <= Mission.date_start,
                    CarGPS.end_date >= Mission.date_start))
query = query.outerjoin(
        GPS, and_(GPS.gps_id == CarGPS.gps_id,
                  GPS.start_date <= Mission.date_start,
                  GPS.end_date >= Mission.date_start))
```

But i want to do it through relations, not by join/outerjoin.
Thank you!

SQLAlchemy version: sqlalchemy==1.0.14

Python version: 3.5.1